# $E[Y^2| (X-Y)^+]$ for $X,Y\stackrel{iid}\sim Unif(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, independence

I am preparing for a test and am unsure of my workings on this exercise:

> Calculate $E[Y^2| (X-Y)^+]$ for $X,Y\stackrel{iid}\sim Unif(0,1)$

Where $A^+ = \max (A,0)$

My approach was to calculate the transformation $U = X-Y, V = Y$ and get the expected value 
$$E[Y^2|X-Y] = E[V^2| U]$$
Which was equal to $\frac {(1-U)^3}{3} I_{(0,1)}(U) + (\frac 13 + \frac {U^3}2) I_{(-1,0)}(U)$. I used this in the following manner
$$E[V^2| U^+] = E[E[V^2|U]|U^+]$$
Which led to two cases
$$U\in (0,1):\; \frac 13 E[(1-U)^3| U^+] = \frac 13 E[(1-U)^3| U] = \frac 13 (1-U)^3$$
$$U \in (-1,0): \; \frac 12 E[U^3|U^+] + \frac 13 = \frac 12 E[U^3] + \frac 13$$

I am frankly quite confused at this point as to what I'm actually doing. Questions:

1. $E[(1-U)^3| U^+] = E[(1-U)^3| U]$ is fair since $[U \in (0,1)] = [U^+ \in (0,1)]$ is that correct?
2. $E[U^3|U^+ ] = E[U^3]$ because $U^3 \bot U^+$, given $U\in (-1,0)$
3. More importantly, this all seems very dodgy. The whole two-cases business is quite unjustified in my mind and I am not sure, for example, what $E[U^3]$ is now supposed to be if $U\in (-1,0)$. My guess is it'd be zero as we're dealing with the triangular (symmetric) distribution and we're only saying the expression equals for $U\in (-1,0)$. But this would render 2. untrue, if I apply the knowledge of what values I am currently considering only after I do the calculation - as I said, I am confused.

I'd appreciate an attempt at clearing this up in my head.

Thanks!

edit: it is entirely possible I made a calculation error, however, that should not matter - it is the general confusion with the approach that needs clarifying, not the result itself.

Comment: Well $U=X-Y$, I used that to calculate the auxiliary conditional expectation and used the tower rule (/law of total expectation) to use that to calculate the original.

Comment: In full generality, $$E(Z\mid Z^+)=z\,\mathbf 1_{Z^+=0}+Z^+$$ where $$z=E(Z\mid Z\leqslant 0)=E(Z\mid Z^+=0)=\frac{-E(Z^-)}{P(Z\leqslant0)}.$$

Comment: I don't understand the notation here. I know how to compute something like $E\left(Y^2\middle|X-Y\gt0\right)$, but what does $E\left(Y^2\middle|(X-Y)^+\right)$ mean? I am used to the quantity on the right of the bar being a true/false condition rather than a real number.

Comment: @robjohn I think it's the random variable $\max\{X-Y,0\}$? So that = $E[Y^2|X-Y] = E[Y^2|U]$ if U > 0 and = $E[Y^2| \sigma(0)] = E[Y^2| \{\Omega, \emptyset\}] = E[Y^2]$ if $U < 0$

Comment: @robjohn as BCLC correctly said, it's the random variable $\max \{X-Y,0\}$

Comment: I know what $(X-Y)^+$ means, but what does it mean to put a non-truth value on the right of the vertical bar?

Comment: Well $E[X|Y]$ where $X,Y$ are random variables is usually defined as $E[X|\sigma (Y)]$, more on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2

Comment: @DahnJahn: thanks! That link answered my question.

Comment: @DahnJahn Did you note my first comment fully answers your question?